# SuiteCRM rendering format of variable in pdf template (like date)

Tags: suitecrm

on SuiteCRM-7.8.13

**I could not find any answer to a [question, like the one in this link,](https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/developer-help/349-change-date-format-in-pdf-template#65347) about rendering format of variable in PDF template on search engines and SO. You'll find here the result of my investigation.**

PDF templates fields that were not formated as I needed and among them the date.

The rendering on the PDF template of the var  `$aos_quotes_date_entered` was month/day/year + time in am/pm style.

I just wanted the date with the order day/month/year to match the french style I needed.

I delved into the code and found where to alter it.

**IT IS NOT CLEAN, JUST A HINT, BUT MIGHT HELP OTHERS (AND SAVE THEM TIME)**

In file: `[SuiteCRM-7.8.13 folder]\modules\AOS_PDF_Templates\templateParser.php`

The class (I will comment the code of the class to point out where to look):

```
class templateParser {
    static function parse_template($string, $bean_arr) {
        //no comment on that function
    }

    function parse_template_bean($string, $key, &$focus){
        //some code


        foreach ($focus->field_defs as $field_def) {
           // some code in the loop
        }

        //some code


        //this is the loop where you can catch the var $aos_quotes_date_entered and alter its value
        foreach ($repl_arr as $name => $value) {
          //several check are done on some var

            //add your own check on the $name and alter the value as you wish it to appear on the pdf generated document
            if($name === 'aos_quotes_date_entered'){
                 $value = [alter the date with correct format]
           }

        }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be a change that is not upgrade-safe. TemplateParsing is an area that needs a lot of attention, it lacks basic stuff like what you want to do +  [this](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/pull/5301) or [this](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/pull/4266)

This is what I do when I need a format different on what is stored in the  DB and also when I have custom sugarFields

## 1 create a new text field (e.g. `date_entered_french_format_c` in this example ), like it is explained [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp5vVn8O-Ks)

**NB:** the new textfield won't alter the database table (`aos_quote` in that case), instead the textfield is defined in the table `fields_meta_data` and the values of the field `date_entered_french_format_c` related to tuples in `aos_quote` will be store  `aos_quotes_cstm` (`<module>_cstm` to make it generic to other modules).

## 2 create  an after_save logic_hook in aos_quotes (3 steps):

Here is the reference documentation for creating a module logic hook
[SugarCRM CE Docs](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/after_save/)

**step #1:**
in `[suitecrm folder]/custom/Extension/modules/AOS_Quotes/Ext/LogicHooks/after_save_logic_hooks.php`:

```
  <?php

    $hook_array['after_save'] = Array();
    $hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(1, 'after save', 'custom/modules/AOS_Quotes/AOSQuotesAfterSaveClass.php','AOSQuotesAfterSaveClass','after_save_method');
    

    ?>
```

**step #2:** parse your date fields and format them to your needs

in `[suitecrm folder]/custom/modules/AOS_Quotes/AOSQuotesAfterSaveClass.php`:

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class AOSQuotesAfterSaveClass
    {
        function after_save_method($bean, $event, $arguments)
        {
            //logic
            $date_entered = (empty($bean->fetched_row['id']))?((new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')):$bean->fetched_row['date_entered'];
            $date_entered_as_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date_entered);
            $date_format_to_french = $date_entered_as_date->format('d-m-Y');
            $bean->date_entered_french_format_c = $date_format_to_french;
            $bean->save();

        }
    }

?>
```

**step #3:** Do a repair rebuild [like explained here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Troubleshooting/Performing_a_Quick_Repair_and_Rebuild/).

## 3 include the new fields instead of the default ones ( `date_entered_french_format_c` is usable in your PDF template)

Comment: I agree with you: It is not upgrade-safe. The solution you propose seems interesting to explore. Could you detail where to look in the developper doc to achieve those steps? I have an idea when I look on search engine but I'd rather have your confirmation about it to just read about the part I need and not the full suitecrm-sugarcrm documentation.

Comment: Just edited my answer so you have the link to the documentation :)

Comment: Where to look for the create new text field part?

Comment: Thats the easy part, go to the Admin section, find Studio, then pick the module (aos_quotes), click on Fields and then click on Add field. The rest is just field name and type (text)