# bean object in hooks: What are the rules to allow access to a field as a property or in an array() belonging to property fetched_row

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

In suitecrm 7.8, I have been investigating the `after_save` logic hook functionnality ([see answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198547/suitecrm-rendering-format-of-variable-in-pdf-template-like-date)).

**I had a bit of struggles to get with a consistent pattern the value of an existing field from a `SugarBean` object in the `after_save_class_method` implemented for a given module in `[suitecrm folder]/custom/modules/<module name>/<after save class name>.php`.**

I explain:
In `AOS_Quotes` to get the value of the field `date_entered` I had to do:
            `$date_entered = $bean->fetched_row['date_entered'];`

If I'd tried `$bean->date_entered`, the property would not exist on the object while other properties being fields where directly accessible through that pattern.

Whereas in `AOS_Products_Quotes` if I'd tried to get the value of a field thru properties `$bean->fetched_row[{field_name}]` it would not work and I had to get the field using this pattern: `$bean->{field_name}`.

To understand what was going thru I placed a `var_dump($bean)` in both of my `<after save class name>`, the one regarding `AOS_Quotes` and the one regarding `AOS_Products_Quotes`:

```
<?php

    if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class <after save class name>
    {
        function after_save_method($bean, $event, $arguments)
        {
            //logic
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($bean);
            echo '</pre>';
            exit;


        }
    }

?>
```

In the one regarding the 'AOS_Quotes' the result of the var_dump gives:

```
object(AOS_Quotes)#46 (141) {
    ...
    ["fetched_row"]=>
    array(51) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(36) "<some id>",
      ....
    }
    ...
}
```

It confirms a property `fetched_row` exists on the object `AOS_Quotes`. I could access most of the fields with the pattern `$bean->{field_name}` except the one named `date_entered`, (My guess is that `date_entered` is not supposed to be altered by the user in an after_save hook hence should not be accessible as a property)

In the one regarding the 'AOS_Products_Quotes' the result of the var_dump gives:

```
object(AOS_Products_Quotes)#428 (94) {
...
  ["fetched_row"]=>
  bool(false)
...
}
```

It confirms no property `fetched_row` existed on the object `AOS_Products_Quotes`.

**I wonder what were the rules and setting to set accessibility in a SugarBean object either:**

- **in a property `fetched_row` containing the `<field_name>` in an `array()`;**
- **Or having the `<field_name>` directly as a property of the SugarBean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the way SugarCRM/SuiteCRM handles NEW vs Existing beans.

Fetched row is used to get previous value before the update. 
If its empty, it means the bean is being created.

`$date_entered = $bean->fetched_row['date_entered'];`

This value is the one going to be save.

`$date_entered = $bean->date_entered;`

In fact, to detect that you are dealing with a CREATION and not an EDIT you can check for an empty  `$bean->fetched_row['id']` this is empty for newly created entities.

Comment: Also in after_save hooks you can check if the bean was new by using `$arguments['isUpdate']` (will be `false` for new beans, `true` for existing ones).

Comment: @Jay, `arguments` is empty in the case I try. The methodology of the answer seems to be more reliable to check if this is a tuple creation case or not.

Comment: @nyluje thanks for letting me know. Maybe it's just not a thing in suitecrm (I misread as sugarcrm, so my bad really)